# arcpy.CalculateField_management doesn't recognize variable in code block

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-script-tool, parameters, error-000539

I found a useful field calculator code block that I'm trying to add to a custom python tool. It works great in the manual field calculator; however, when inserted into the code block text to be used as a script, I get "NameError: name 'fc' is not defined". Apparently the script isn't seeing my variable. My question then is: How do I get the variable inside the code block?

I've tried everything I can think of including but not limited to setting 'fc' as global, escaping 'fc' from the code block string, and defining 'rows' outside of the code block, but I seem to be getting nowhere. I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I'm out of ideas for today.  Below is my code and the error:

```
import arcpy

fc=arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

DupNumCode="""uniquelist = {}
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
  value = row.getValue('SpatialID')
  if value not in uniquelist:
    uniquelist[value] = 1
  else:
    uniquelist[value] = uniquelist[value] + 1

def findIncidence(inValue):  
  return uniquelist[inValue]"""

DupNumExpression="findIncidence(!SpatialID!)"

arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "DupNum", DupNumExpression, "PYTHON", DupNumCode)
```

I get the following:

```
ExecuteError: ERROR 000539: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
NameError: name 'fc' is not defined

Failed to execute (CalculateField).
```

Here is my parameter setup:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how you're defining parameters in the python script tool (from the toolbox)?

Comment: You can edit your post and after saving your image to a file upload it into the post as a picture.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  To edit your question, click [Edit] under your question (or in this comment).

Answer (score 2):

Your `fc` is not definied within the code block.  You can pass it to the code block using [string format](https://pyformat.info/):

```
DupNumCode = """uniquelist = dict()
fc = {0}
rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc)
for row in rows:
  value = row.getValue('SpatialID')
  if value not in uniquelist:
    uniquelist[value] = 1
  else:
    uniquelist[value] = uniquelist[value] + 1

def findIncidence(inValue):  
  return uniquelist[inValue]""".format(fc)
```

Note that I have changed `uniquelist = {}` to be `uniquelist = dict()` to ensure the `format` doesn't try to insert into the `{}` here.

Comment: You've got unbalanced quotes in the first line of code

Comment: @Vince unsure what you mean here?  Triple quotes open the code block, triple quotes close the code block.

Comment: Doh.  I see it now. But I expect the `{0}` will cause trouble.  Sometimes it's more readable to append individual lines as strings.

Comment: It's the combination of `{}` and `{0}` within a format that's scary.

Comment: I have updated it to remove the ambiguity

Comment: Thanks everyone! @Midavalo I edited the code according to your suggestion, yet I'm still getting the same error. I did find, however, that if I define both 'fc' and 'rows' variables outside of the code block together, they both become recognized (??). Unfortunately, I'm now getting a new error wherein it appears that the values are being passed into the function as Unicode. ie    
    (u"457551.0390114599721.07082") 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 10, in findIncidence
KeyError: u'457551.0390114599721.07082'

Comment: @gw13 did you include the `.format(fc)` at the end of the code block?